# How to use Mockito without maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito

I want to write some tests using mockito, but my project is not a maven project, so I cannot add the dependency as the mockito documentation suggests.

So I downloaded `mockito-core-2.21.0-javadoc.jar`, `mockito-core-2.21.0.jar` and `mockito-core-2.21.0-sources.jar` and added them to my project as wrapped jars.

I can import the libraries and all that stuff, but it seems that mockito doesn't work.

I tried this simple example taken from [here](https://gojko.net/2009/10/23/mockito-in-six-easy-examples/):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.junit.Test;
....
 @Test
 public void iterator_will_return_hello_world(){
  //arrange
  Iterator i=mock(Iterator.class);
  when(i.next()).thenReturn("Hello").thenReturn("World");
  //act
  String result=i.next()+" "+i.next();
  //assert
  assertEquals("Hello World", result);
 }
```

However, when running the test, it fails. The line where it fails is `Iterator i=mock(Iterator.class);`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you add a stack trace so that we can see how exactly it fails?

Comment: @hinson thanks for the attention. Here it is: [https://pastebin.com/Ghp1pGHj](https://pastebin.com/Ghp1pGHj)

Comment: The answer to almost every question that includes "... but I'm not building with Maven" is "change to build with maven."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito has transitive dependencies to non-Mockito projects.
Here is the output of a "mvn dependency:tree" run:

```
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.8.47:test
[INFO]    +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.14:test
[INFO]    +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.6.14:test
[INFO]    \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.5:test
```

Based on that,
you need to add the bytebuddy and objenesis jars to your non-maven build.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the stack trace you provided in a comment, it looks like your project is still missing other dependencies. So, you will have to download these manually as well.

The stack trace points to "net.bytebuddy", and you can take a look at compile dependencies here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0

I tried to run the sample myself, and these are dependencies I had to manually include to make things work:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.8.15
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.8.15
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.objenesis/objenesis/2.6
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm/6.2.1
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12

One way to find out which dependencies are needed is to actually use maven dependency tree command.